# Get-Date inside Where or Where-Object

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have this

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint/mysubsite"
$list=$web.Lists["Scanned Documents"]
foreach ($item in $list.Items | where {$_.Indicator -ne "Expired"})  {
    write-host $item[“Expiry Date”];
    $olddate = Get-Date -Date $item[“Expiry Date”]
    $Now = Get-Date 
    if ($olddate -lt $Now) {
        $item[“Indicator”] = "Expired";
    } else {
        $item[“Indicator”] = " ";
    }
    $item.SystemUpdate();
}
```

which works fine - but the list could be really really big, so wanted something a bit more like this.

```
foreach ($item in $list.Items | Where-Object { ($_.Indicator -ne "Expired") -and (Get-Date -Date $_."Expiry Date" -lt $Now) }) {
    #you get the idea
}
```

But I cannot get it working - complains about using `Get-Date` inside the `Where-Object`.

I tried

```
foreach ($item in $list.Items | Where-Object { ($_.Indicator -ne "Expired") -and $_."Expiry Date" -lt $Now }) {
    #you get the idea
}
```

which executes, but brings back all the items not just the expired dates.

Comment: Mis-placed brackets. There's nothing wrong with using `Get-Date` there, but you need it to be `... -and (Get-Date -Date $_."Expiry Date") -lt $Now`.

Comment: I get this Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target "Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fragment

```
 ... (Get-Date -Date $_."Expiry Date" -lt $Now) ...
```

the `-lt` is considered a parameter to the `Get-Date` cmdlet. To make it explicit where the cmdlet's parameter list ends just wrap it in another pair or parentheses like this

```
 ... ((Get-Date -Date $_."Expiry Date") -lt $Now) ...
```

Comment: I get this Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target "Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys - after a bit of trial and error I got it working with

```
foreach ($item in $list.Items | where-Object {($_["Indicator"] -ne "Expired") -and ((Get-Date -Date $_["Expiry Date"]) -lt $Now) }) {
```